# IIS 10.0 Request Filtering / Allow unlisted file name extensions won't work as expected

Tags: iis, request, filtering, sql-injection, requestfiltering

I have unchecked the option *allow unlisted file name extensions* , and then added all the following extensions with which I am working with.

- .cfm (allow)
- .cfc (allow)
- .js (allow)
- .css (allow)
- .jpg (allow)
- .png (allow)
- .gif (allow)
- .woff (allow)
- .woff2 (allow)

Everything works great, however when I attempt to make a call of one of my CFML components, such as

```
/mywebsite.com/mvc.cfc?method=getCustomers
```

then the request is blocked. I would expect that this wouldn't be blocked as the extension of mvc.cfc is a .cfc which is a member of the allowed list.

Could you please help understand what is going on? If I enter any other extension such as .js or .cfm , all is ok, the only problem is with the .cfc though.

Thank you

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis See what FRT says.

Comment: Have you added .cfc file name extensions in request filtering? you can check it in Request Filtering. or you can also use fiddler to check which request caused the error.

Comment: @samwu yes of course .cfc is added, it's also shown on the list I originally posted above.

How can I use fiddler to check this? problem is on the server-end not client request. What do u mean?

Comment: @LexLi this is not a failed request. It's a failed request filtering. Two totally different things mate.

Comment: @OrangeG If you set status code in FRT rules to 200-999, you can literally trace any requests and see how each IIS modules/handlers work on each of them, and then finding the answer just takes you a few seconds.

Answer (score 2):

it appears that the workaround is easy. with .cfc and .cfm you also need to allow .dll too So, just adding this at the web.config , did the trick.

```
<add fileExtension=".dll" allowed="true" />
```